# Can't split up JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, scope

I am stuck with this annoying problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I want to take a JSON file and only show that information I find relevant. But somehow I can only show the whole thing, and not choose, for example, `{{post.title}}`.

Here is the JSON I want to use: http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=frozen&y=&plot=short&r=json

This is my controller:

```
.controller('View5Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) 

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        //url: '/test/allMovies/test'
        url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=frozen&y=&plot=short&r=json',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.posts = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = data;
        });
});
```

And this is my HTML file

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
<div id="div">
    <p>
        {{post.title}}
    </p>
    <p></p>
    </p>
</div>
```

By this, I only get a bunch of empty paragraphs. But if I remove the `.title`, I get the whole thing out.

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks for the answers! I will post the solution here for future viewers.

```
<div id="div">
  <p>
   {{posts.Title}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: posts is an object and not an array. If you want to show the title use posts.Title

Comment: My bad, but this does still not solve my problem. Nothing shows up?

Comment: #Gruff Bunny, do you mean post or posts? If i say posts.Genre, i will get the genres printed out 20 times. If i use posts.Title it prints "xXx" 20 times.

Comment: The response returned via the request is a single object. The $scope.posts is set to that response so I would expect posts.Title to show 'Frozen'.

Comment: Okay. But like i said, it just prints out xXx 20 times.

Comment: As @GruffBunny said, your json's a single object. You either need to do `$scope.posts=[data]` in you success handler or get rid of the `ng-repeat`. As it stands you're trying to iterate over a single object, when what you need is an array.

Comment: Thanks guys. I deleted the ng-repeat in the code, and used posts.Title to get the information. Thanks for helping me out!